# 'Tareas' object has no attribute '__fields__'

Tags: django, admin, field

When i try to access to 'tareas' the app returns to me as follows:

```
 'Tareas' object has no attribute '__fields__'
  Request Method:   GET
  Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/tareas/
  Django Version:   1.4
  Exception Type:   AttributeError
  Exception Value:  
  'Tareas' object has no attribute '__fields__'
  Exception Location:   /Users/Tone/Documents/Proyectos/macrotelecom/common/generic.py in      view_list, line 240
```

The problem is in this line:

```
if not fields:
    fields=queryset.__dict__['model']().__fields__(profile)
```

Which I think is weird because in admin.py i set the attribute fields for my object 'Tareas':

```
  from tareas.models import Tareas
  from django.contrib import admin

  class TareasAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     fields = ['idtarea','idtipotarea','idagente','fechatarea']
     list_display = ('idtarea','idagente','fechatarea')

admin.site.register(Tareas,TareasAdmin)
```

The line is defined in this function 'def_view':

```
 def view_list(request, get_template, **kwargs):
        '''
        Generic list view with validation included and object transfering support
        '''

        # Config
        default_rows_per_page=100

        # Get arguments from the function
        object_id=keyarg('object_id',kwargs,None)
        action=keyarg('action',kwargs,None)
        extra_context=keyarg('extra_context',kwargs,{})
        queryset=keyarg('queryset',kwargs,None)
        restrictions=keyarg('restrictions',kwargs,None)
        permission=keyarg('permission',kwargs,None)
        fields=keyarg('fields',kwargs,None)
        default_ordering=keyarg('default_ordering',kwargs,None)
        compact_rows=keyarg('compact_rows',kwargs,None)

        # Get template and profile
        namesp=str(queryset.__dict__['model']).replace("class ","").replace(">","").replace("<","").replace("'","").split(".")
        appname=namesp[-3].lower()
        modelname=namesp[-1].lower()
        (profile,template_name)=get_template(keyarg('template_name',kwargs,"%s/%s_list.html" % (appname,modelname)))

        # Check permissions
        if (permission is not None) and (not request.user.has_perm(permission)):
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/not_authorized/')

        # Get extra arguments
        extra={}
        for arg in kwargs:
            if arg not in ['object_id','action','template_name','extra_context','queryset','restrictions']:
                extra[arg]=kwargs[arg]

        # Inicialization
        new_extra_context={}
        new_extra_context['now']=epochdate(time.time())
    #    new_extra_context['msglog']=msglog()
        # Restrictions fields
        new_extra_context['filters']=[]
        if restrictions:
            for restriction in restrictions:
                f={}
                f['name']=restriction
                f['value']=extra[restriction]
                new_extra_context['filters'].append(f)

        # Process the filter
        new_extra_context['filters_obj']={}
        new_extra_context['header_loop']=1
        if restrictions:
            queryset_obj={}
            for rname in restrictions:
                # Get name of the field and object
                (rfield,robject)=restrictions[rname]
                # Get the ID
                rid=extra[rname]
                # Save the id in extra_context
                new_extra_context[rname]=rid
                # Save the object in queryset_obj
                queryset_obj[rname]=robject(id=rid)
                # Filter the queryset
                queryset=queryset.filter(eval("Q(%s=queryset_obj['%s'])" % (rfield,rname)))
                new_extra_context['filters_obj'][rname]=get_object_or_404(robject,pk=rid)

        # Get field list
        if not fields:
            fields=queryset.__dict__['model']().__fields__(profile)

        # Save action if we got one
        if action:
            new_extra_context['action']=action
        # Try to convert object_id to a numeric id
        try:
            object_id=int(object_id)
        except:
            pass

        # Save GET values
        new_extra_context['get']=[]
        new_extra_context['getval']={}
        for name in request.GET:
            if name not in ['filtername','filtervalue']:
                struct={}
                struct['name']=name
                if name=='rowsperpage':
                    struct['value']=default_rows_per_page
                elif name=='page':
                    struct['value']=1
                else:
                    struct['value']=request.GET[name]
                new_extra_context['get'].append(struct)
                new_extra_context['getval'][name]=struct['value']

        # Filter on limits
        limits=queryset.__dict__['model']().__limitQ__(profile,request)
        qobjects=None
        for name in limits:
            if qobjects:
                qobjects&=limits[name]
            else:
                qobjects=limits[name]
        if qobjects:
            queryset=queryset.filter(qobjects)

        # Filters on fields
        try:
            filters_by_json=request.GET.get('filters','{}')
            filters_by_struct=json_decode(str(filters_by_json))
        except Exception:
            filters_by_struct=[]
        filtername=request.GET.get('filtername',None)
        filtervalue=request.GET.get('filtervalue',None)
        listfilters=queryset.__dict__['model']().__searchF__(profile)

        # Process the search
        filters_struct={}
        for key in filters_by_struct:
            # Get the value of the original filter
            value=filters_by_struct[key]
            # If there is something to filter, filter is not being changed and filter is known by the class
            if (key!=filtername) and (key in listfilters) and (value>0):
                # Add the filter to the queryset
                f=listfilters[key]
                fv=f[2][value-1][0]
                queryset=queryset.filter(f[1](fv))
                # Save it in the struct as a valid filter
                filters_struct[key]=value

        # Add the requested filter if any
        if (filtername in listfilters) and (int(filtervalue)>0):
            f=listfilters[filtername]
            fv=f[2][int(filtervalue)-1][0]
            queryset=queryset.filter(f[1](fv))
            filters_struct[filtername]=int(filtervalue)

        # Rewrite filters_json updated
        filters_json=json_encode(filters_struct)

        # Build the clean get for filters
        get=new_extra_context['get']
        filters_get=[]
        for element in get:
            if element['name'] not in ['filters']:
                struct={}
                struct['name']=element['name']
                struct['value']=element['value']
                filters_get.append(struct)

        # Add filter_json
        struct={}
        struct['name']='filters'
        struct['value']=filters_json
        filters_get.append(struct)
        new_extra_context['filters_get']=filters_get

        # Get the list of filters allowed by this class
        filters=[]
        for key in listfilters:
            choice=[_('All')]
            for value in listfilters[key][2]:
                choice.append(value[1])

            # Decide the choosen field
            if key in filters_struct.keys():
                choose=int(filters_struct[key])
            else:
                choose=0

            filters.append((key,listfilters[key][0],choice,choose))
        new_extra_context['filters']=filters


        # Search text in all fields
        search=request.GET.get('search','')
        new_extra_context['search']=search
        datetimeQ=None
        if len(search)>0:
            searchs=queryset.__dict__['model']().__searchQ__(search,profile)
            qobjects=None
            for name in searchs:
                if (searchs[name]=='datetime'):
                    datetimeQ=name
                    continue
                else:
                    if qobjects:
                        qobjects|=searchs[name]
                    else:
                        qobjects=searchs[name]
            if qobjects:
                queryset=queryset.filter(qobjects)
        else:
            # Look for datetimeQ field
            searchs=queryset.__dict__['model']().__searchQ__(search,profile)
            for name in searchs:
                if (searchs[name]=='datetime'):
                    datetimeQ=name
                    continue

        # Datetime Q
        new_extra_context['datetimeQ']=datetimeQ
        if datetimeQ:
            # Inicialization
            f={}
            f['year']=(1900,2100,False)
            f['month']=(1,12,False)
            f['day']=(1,31,False)
            f['hour']=(0,23,False)
            f['minute']=(0,59,False)
            f['second']=(0,59,False)
            date_elements=[None,'year','month','day','hour','minute','second']
            # Get configuration of dates and set limits to the queryset
            for element in date_elements[1:]:
                value=request.GET.get(element,None)
                if value:
                    f[element]=(int(value),int(value),True)
            if f['year'][2] and f['month'][2] and not f['day'][2]:
                (g,lastday)=calendar.monthrange(f['year'][1],f['month'][1])
                f['day']=(f['day'][0],lastday,f['day'][2])
            # Limits
            date_min=datetime.datetime(f['year'][0], f['month'][0], f['day'][0], f['hour'][0], f['minute'][0], f['second'][0])
            date_max=datetime.datetime(f['year'][1], f['month'][1], f['day'][1], f['hour'][1], f['minute'][1], f['second'][1])
            queryset=queryset.filter(eval("( Q(%s__gte=date_min) & Q(%s__lte=date_max) ) | Q(%s=None)" % (datetimeQ,datetimeQ,datetimeQ)))

            # Find actual deepness
            deepness_index=0
            for element in date_elements[1:]:
                if f[element][2]:
                    deepness_index+=1
                else:
                    break

            # Get results from dates to set the new order
            date_results=queryset.values_list(datetimeQ, flat=True) #.dates(datetimeQ,'day')
            if f['day'][0]!=f['day'][1]:
                if f['month'][0]==f['month'][1]:
                    date_results=date_results.dates(datetimeQ,'day')
                elif f['year'][0]==f['year'][1]:
                    date_results=date_results.dates(datetimeQ,'month')
                else:
                    date_results=date_results.dates(datetimeQ,'year')

            get=new_extra_context['get']
            new_extra_context['datefilter']={}
            # Save the deepness
            if (deepness_index+1==len(date_elements)):
                new_extra_context['datefilter']['deepness']=None
            else:
                new_extra_context['datefilter']['deepness']=date_elements[deepness_index+1]
            new_extra_context['datefilter']['deepnessback']=[]
            new_extra_context['datefilter']['deepnessinit']=[]
            for element in get:
                if (not element['name'] in date_elements):
                    struct={}
                    struct['name']=element['name']
                    struct['value']=element['value']
                    new_extra_context['datefilter']['deepnessinit'].append(struct)
                    new_extra_context['datefilter']['deepnessback'].append(struct)
                elif (element['name']!=date_elements[deepness_index] and f[element['name']][2]):
                    struct={}
                    struct['name']=element['name']
                    struct['value']=element['value']
                    new_extra_context['datefilter']['deepnessback'].append(struct)
            # Build the list of elements
            new_extra_context['datefilter']['data']=[]
            for element in date_results:
                # Save the data
                new_extra_context['datefilter']['data'].append(element.timetuple()[deepness_index])
            new_extra_context['datefilter']['data']=list(set(new_extra_context['datefilter']['data']))
            new_extra_context['datefilter']['data'].sort()

            # Prepare the rightnow result
            if f['month'][2]:
                month=_(month_name(f['month'][0]))
            else:
                month='__'
            if f['hour'][2]:
                rightnow="%s/%s/%s %s:%s:%s" % (grv(f,'day'),month,grv(f,'year'),grv(f,'hour'),grv(f,'minute'),grv(f,'second'))
            else:
                rightnow="%s/%s/%s" % (grv(f,'day'),month,grv(f,'year'))
            new_extra_context['datefilter']['rightnow']=rightnow

        # Distinct
        queryset=queryset.distinct()

        # Ordering field autofill
        try:
            order_by_json=request.GET.get('ordering','[]')
            order_by_struct=json_decode(str(order_by_json))
        except Exception:
            order_by_struct=[]
        order_by=[]
        position={}
        counter=1
        for order in order_by_struct:
            name=order.keys()[0]
            direction=order[name]
            if direction=='asc':
                order_by.append("%s" % (name))
            elif direction=='desc':
                order_by.append("-%s" % (name))
            position[name]=counter
            counter+=1
        if order_by:
            queryset=queryset.order_by(*order_by)
        elif default_ordering:
            queryset=queryset.order_by(default_ordering)
        else:
            queryset=queryset.order_by("pk")
        # Check the total count of registers
        total_registers=queryset.count()

        # Ordering field autofill
        sort={}
        for value in fields:
            # Get values
            name=value[0]
            publicname=value[1]
            if len(value)>2:
                size=value[2]
            else:
                size=None
            if len(value)>3:
                align=value[3]
            else:
                align=None
            # Process ordering
            ordering=[]
            found=False
            for order in order_by_struct:
                subname=order.keys()[0]
                direction=order[subname]
                if name==subname:
                    if direction == 'desc':
                        direction = ''
                        sort_class='headerSortUp'
                    elif direction == 'asc':
                        direction = 'desc'
                        sort_class='headerSortDown'
                    else:
                        sort_class=''
                        direction = 'asc'
                    found=True
                if direction == 'asc' or direction=='desc':
                    ordering.append({subname:direction})
            if not found:
                ordering.append({name:'asc'})
                sort_class=''
            # Save the ordering method
            sort[name]={}
            sort[name]['id']=name
            sort[name]['name']=publicname
            sort[name]['class']=sort_class
            sort[name]['size']=size
            sort[name]['align']=align
            if name:
                sort[name]['ordering']=json_encode(ordering).replace('"','\\"')
            if name in position:
                sort[name]['position']=position[name]

        # Pagination
        # IMPORTANT: This part is commented because I don't manage to control rowsperpage from urls.py file, it is remembering last query instead
        # vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
        #if 'rowsperpage' in extra_context:
        #    rowsperpage=extra_context['rowsperpage']
        #else:
        #    rowsperpage=default_rows_per_page
        #total_rows_per_page=request.GET.get('rowsperpage',rowsperpage)
        # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        total_rows_per_page=request.GET.get('rowsperpage',default_rows_per_page)
        if total_rows_per_page:
            try:
                total_rows_per_page = int(total_rows_per_page)
            except Exception:
                total_rows_per_page = 'All'
        else:
            # IMPORTANT: Commented as before coded
            # total_rows_per_page = rowsperpage
            total_rows_per_page = default_rows_per_page
        if total_rows_per_page == 'All':
            page_number=1
            total_rows_per_page = total_registers
            total_rows_per_page_out = _('All')
            total_pages=1
        else:
            total_rows_per_page = int(total_rows_per_page) # By default 10 rows per page
            total_rows_per_page_out = total_rows_per_page
            total_pages=total_registers/total_rows_per_page
            if total_registers%total_rows_per_page:
                total_pages+=1
            page_number=request.GET.get('page',1)                  # If no page specified use first page
            if page_number=='last':
                page_number=total_pages
            else:
                try:
                    page_number=int(page_number)
                except:
                    page_number=1
                if page_number>total_pages:
                    page_number=total_pages

        # Build the list of page counters allowed
        choice=[]
        c=default_rows_per_page
        chk=1
        while total_registers>=c:
            choice.append(c)
            if chk==1:
                # From 5 to 10
                c=c*2
                # Next level
                chk=2
            elif chk==2:
                # From 10 to 25 (10*2+10/2)
                c=c*2+c/2
                # Next level
                chk=3
            elif chk==3:
                # From 25 to 50
                c*=2
                chk=1
        # Add all choice in any case
        choice.append(_('All'))
        # Save the pagination in the structure
        new_extra_context['rowsperpageallowed']=choice
        new_extra_context['rowsperpage']=total_rows_per_page_out
        new_extra_context['pagenumber']=page_number

        if type(object_id)==type(u'abc'):
            # If object_id is a string, we have a name not an object
            new_extra_context['object_name']=object_id
            object_obj = None
        else:
            # If is not an string
            if object_id:
                # If we got one, load the object
                obj=extra_context['obj']
                object_obj = get_object_or_404(obj, pk=object_id)
            else:
                # There is no object
                object_obj = None
            new_extra_context['object_obj']=object_obj

        # Build the columns structure
        new_extra_context['columns']=[]
        for value in fields:
            field=value[0]
            new_extra_context['columns'].append(sort[field])

        # Get the full number of registers and save it to extra_context
        new_extra_context['total_registers']=total_registers
        if total_rows_per_page=='All':
            # Remove total_rows_per_page if is all
            total_rows_per_page=None
            new_extra_context['page_before']=None
            new_extra_context['page_after']=None
            new_extra_context['start_register']=1
            new_extra_context['showing_registers']=total_registers
        else:
            # Page before
            if page_number<=1:
                new_extra_context['page_before']=None
            else:
                new_extra_context['page_before']=page_number-1
            # Page after
            if page_number>=total_pages:
                new_extra_context['page_after']=None
            else:
                new_extra_context['page_after']=page_number+1
            # Starting on register number
            new_extra_context['start_register']=(page_number-1)*total_rows_per_page+1
            new_extra_context['showing_registers']=total_rows_per_page

        # Calculate end
        new_extra_context['end_register']=min(new_extra_context['start_register']+new_extra_context['showing_registers']-1,total_registers)

        # If compact rows
        hide_head=[]
        hide_tail=[]
        hide_subhead=[]
        hide_subtail=[]
        if compact_rows:
            (compact_field,compact_subelements)=compact_rows
            lastvalue=None
            lastrow=None
            total_subelements=0
            for row in queryset:
                value=eval("row.%s" % (compact_field))
                # Count the subelements from this row
                if compact_subelements:
                    count_subelements=eval("row.%s.count()" % (compact_subelements))
                else:
                    count_subelements=1
                # If the new row belongs to the same group than the row before
                if value==lastvalue:
                    # Hide the head from this row
                    hide_head.append(row.id)
                    # Hide the tail from the last row
                    hide_tail.append(lastrow.id)
                    # If there were elements in the group (somebody already opened the subhead, hide the head of the subgroup) or if this row has no elements (no need to open this subhead)
                    if total_subelements>0 or count_subelements==0:
                        # Hid the subhead
                        hide_subhead.append(row.id)
                    # Hide the tail of the last row, since we want to connect both groups
                    hide_subtail.append(lastrow.id)
                    # Add the total count of elements
                    total_subelements+=count_subelements

                # This row doesn't belong to the opened group
                else:
                    # If there was some row already and there are no elements in the group (nobody opened the group, so we don't have to close it either)
                    if lastrow and total_subelements==0:
                        # Hide the tail from the group
                        hide_subtail.append(lastrow.id)
                    # Startup a new count of elements (Reset the total count of subelements)
                    total_subelements=0
                    total_subelements+=count_subelements
                    # If the new group doesn't have element (we don't think about opening the group)
                    if total_subelements==0:
                        # Hide the head from this group
                        hide_subhead.append(row.id)
                # Remember
                lastvalue=value
                lastrow=row

            # Proper closing the group after the bucle if there was some row opened
            if lastrow and total_subelements==0:
                # Hide the tail from the group if was no element in the group (nobody opened the group)
                hide_subtail.append(lastrow.id)

        # Save it in the public structure
        new_extra_context['hide_head']=hide_head
        new_extra_context['hide_tail']=hide_tail
        new_extra_context['hide_subhead']=hide_subhead
        new_extra_context['hide_subtail']=hide_subtail

        # Save extra context
        extra_context.update(new_extra_context)

        # Empty results are empty
        if page_number==0:
            total_rows_per_page=0

        # Return results
        return object_list(request, queryset=queryset, template_name=template_name, extra_context=extra_context, paginate_by=total_rows_per_page, page=page_number)
```

What it calls in urls.py from 'Tareas':

```
    from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
    from tareas.models import Tareacobro, Tipotarea, Agentes, Perfil, Tareas
    from django.conf import settings
    from common.generic import view_list

    # Uncomment the next two lines to enable the admin:

    info_tasks = {'queryset': Tareas.objects.all()}

    urlpatterns = patterns('tareas.views',
        # =====TASKS======
        # url(r'^$','tareas'),
        (r'^', view_list, dict( info_tasks, extra_context={'obj':Tareas} ),'admin/tareas/tareas'),
        # (r'^$',view_list, dict(info_tasks),'admin/tareas/tareas'),
        #url(r'^$',view_list, dict(info_tasks, extra_context={'obj':Tareas} ),'tareas'),
        )
```

Comment: Is that line from your code? If so you should post the whole function.

Answer (score 0):

`fields=queryset.__dict__['model']()` instantiates a model instance. As an aside, you could use `queryset.model` instead of looking in `__dict__`.

Django models instances do not have an attribute `__fields__`, so you get an attribute error.

If you want to access the fields you have defined in the model admin, you can fetch the model admin class from the registry.

```
from django.contrib.admin import site
model_admin = site._registry[Model]
fields = model_admin.fields
```

Comment: Sorry for that, i'm very newbie in Django so i don't understand more things by now, i have to clarify a bit, the reason i doing with __dict__ is because in urls.py from 'Tareas' i'm calling this, see it in OP, this is for matters of job, we are supply some kind of library that makes custom views and we have to pass a dict as a parameter with the query 'info_tasks' and an extra_content.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. I'm not going to be able to offer you any more advice. Hope you get it working.

Comment: Don't worry, i'll notice this to my partners, thanks for your help!